# Do I need build integration scripts to automate Checkmarx scan in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, checkmarx

I want to automate Checkmarx scan in Jenkins. Means it has to trigger new scan for every build.

For that, do I need any build integration scripts? If I do, where can I find them?

If don't, do you know how can I achieve it?

Thank you in advance and appreciate your help.